# Is there a way to coalesce the top option value in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

is there a way to say if a @topParam value is passed in use that, if not select all.

```
@topParam
select TOP COALESCE ( @topParam, all )
```

Comment: This has such a radical effect on what will be returned it defeats the point of using a stored procedure. Where the point of a stored procedure is to allow precompilation for improved performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not proper solution but temporary its worked for you

```
@topParam
select TOP (COALESCE (@topParam, 1000000000))
```

Think your result set don;t have 1000000000 so it will take all record when @topParam is null.

Enjoy Coding..

Comment: Might as well use the maximum int value: 2147483647

Comment: yeah, that's true. you can use int variable Max value

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I would use `CASE`

```
CASE 
WHEN @topParam > 0 THEN (SELECT WITH LIMIT)
ELSE (SELECT WITHOUT LIMIT)
END
```

Comment: my select statement is very large and contains 15 joins, is there a way which doesn't require me to copy the same code into both of the parantheses

Comment: I haven't tested this but maybe the CASE statement works in the LIMIT section

Answer (score 0):

You are better off making two stored procedures.

A parameter change that radically effects the best query plan is a bad idea for a stored procedure.

On testing with MS SQL 2005 I've noticed that parameterizing the `TOP` statement at all is slower than a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0):

The below syntax also works-

```
SELECT top (@maxNodes) @listOfInvitation = COALESCE(@listOfInvitation + ', ', '') + Cast(InviteID AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM #temp_duplicate_inviteid 
    WHERE cGuid = @cGUID;
```